# The probability of choosing X number of things when there are a total of Y number of things to choose from

Tags: probability, combinations

Let’s give an example here, say there are 10 people in a party, assuming all of them are just mindless zombies who roam around in the room with no free will. What is the probability that 3 of them enter a bedroom. So To put this context mathematically, out of the Y people in the party and X people who enter the bedroom. What is the probability of getting the value of X?

Starting this question out, I thought it would be an easy one

\begin{equation*}
 p = 1/ \binom{x}{y}
\end{equation*}

But  after thinking for awhile, it didn’t really make any sense. Well of course doing x/y was the first thing that came to mind, but if I was to think of it, there would be so many ways to chose something as more of something was chosen. So I came to this conclusion

\begin{equation*}
 p =\binom{x}{y} / (\binom{1}{y} + \binom{2}{y} + ...\binom{y}{y})
\end{equation*}

I’d like some feedback, and clarification if this is correct, still seems rather sketch to me.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. But, you can also choose none from those $Y$. You will also need to incorporate this in your "formula".

Comment: Ohh, so if that was the case, there would be and additional 1 case where none are chosen?

Comment: What do you mean by ${x \choose y}$? I would read it as the number of ways of choosing $y$ items from $x$ but you seem to have reversed this

Comment: Does each zombie enter the bedroom or not each with probability $\frac12$ independently of the other zombies? In other words, is each of the $2^{10}$ possible patterns equally likely

Comment: @Henry is correct in terms of using the notations.

Comment: It is worth noting that some authors in some parts of the world do flip whether the larger number goes on top vs on bottom.  That being said, the attempt seems to suggest that interpretation @henry., though I see no reason why this assumption should be valid... if the doorway to the bedroom were locked and the key on the counter next to it, a mindless zombie might not have the intelligence to unlock the door in order to go in reducing the probabilities drastically

Comment: @Henry Yes assuming that each zombie is independent from each other. Hmmm I’d like to know why you have used 2^10 to express you answer. Is it similar if I was y choose x format?

Comment: The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) shows that the sum of binomial coefficients is equal to $2^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I also think that my example is quite flawed, forgive me. But my question would be that of the probability of a number of things being chosen out a given number of things.

Comment: And even that is a very poorly phrased question.  If I only have two hands and I can only hold one object in each hand at a time... the probability of me having picked a thousand balls out of a ball pit with millions of balls would be zero, simply because I can't hold that many.  It seems you are reaching for the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and specifically for the case of $p=1/2$ but you are missing the rigorous way to phrase the question.

Comment: @JMotavitz hmm ok is my question simply a case of binomial distribution where there are Y number of trials and X number of success, while my probability is 50%?